# How do Facebook graph errors get counted for within the total api errors?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Ever since we started batching our requests our total requests in the App Dashboard API stats went down 50% a day, and our error rate grew by 200% a day.

If you get throttled doing batch requests... n number of requests will return an error. For example:

I make 50 requests in a batch and the first 20 requests are good. At request 21 our account gets throttled, so requests 21-50 all receive a throttling error.

Does this count as 30 errors or 1 error in the API stats?

Comment: Since they still count as individual requests regarding rate limits, I would assume that it only makes sense to count them as individual errors as well.

Comment: @CBroe That would make sense, I was just hoping they would post that somewhere. It's killing our error rate, I guess I just need to slow down the requests. Thanks!